# php-curl very slow total_time only some times

Tags: php, curl

I have this script

```
function curl_file_get_contents($url)
{
 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0');

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.  


 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.   

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    echo "\nOperation completed in ".$info['total_time']." without any errors\n";
    //print_r($info);
}

 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}
```

This is the output of the log:

```
[content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 191
[request_size] => 591
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 26.400935
[namelookup_time] => 0.000829
[connect_time] => 0.000864
[pretransfer_time] => 0.001079
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 123381
[speed_download] => 4673
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.317703
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 176.32.110.148
[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => 37.187.61.23
[local_port] => 46221
[redirect_url] =>
```

Can anyone explain why total_time is very high? This happens only few times, very often during night (about 2.00, 3.00 am).

This is the version installed on my debian server:

```
root@vps31881:~# curl -V
curl 7.26.0 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

And php:

```
root@vps31881:~# php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u3 (cli) (built: Jul 17 2013 17:51:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

If I run curl by terminal, with the same url, same time, it is very fast, I can't explain this!

Comment: `[size_download] => 123381 [speed_download] => 4673` < this. Either _you_, or the server you're connecting to, has bandwidth troubles (or in the case of the server, it may be just slow around that time. 2:00-3:00am seems like a time some single-timezone servers would find a proper time to perform backups & maintenance. having less resources to server clients).

Comment: thanks...but how is this possible since curl invoked by terminal goes faster?

Comment: i'm on a ovh vps and i'm calling amazon xml....i think the speed is related to another problem :(

Comment: Did you... test it from the terminal continuously at least once every minute from 2:00:00 to 3:00:00?

Comment: nope, do you think it is a random behaviour and i was only lucky with terminal calls?

Comment: Well, yes, because I seem to read from your description the code itself in PHP usually runs pretty much OK as well most of the time?

Comment: yes. usually it runs very well :)